# Why is IIS slow on first access, but faster afterwards?

Tags: asp.net, iis, build

After building my asp.net solutions, and then run it for the first time in the browser, the time it takes to load increases. Then running it thereafter the time has decreased until the next build.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When websites are deployed to IIS, the assemblies that make up the site still need to be natively compiled. On first access, the CLR 'interprets' the MSIL and converts it into a binary version specific to the CPU - e.g. x86, x64, Itanium etc.

This also occurs with .EXE's and any outputs from the .NET compiler.

To address this issue with websites taking a while to start up, you can configure pre-compilation to be turned on. See this [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information on the details.

---

From your comment on

> And, from the URL being entered in the browser, how does the .NET compiler know that it needs to convert the MSIL to binary?

IIS stores a list of websites it maintains, and knows what applications service the requests received at those endpoints. For applications written in .NET, IIS will pass the request information to an *ASP.NET pipeline*, which will take the information provided by IIS and place the information into various .NET objects like `HttpContext`, `Session` etc.

From there, the ASP.NET pipeline works out which part of the application responds to that request and executes the code for it.

Comment: Can you expand on the .Net compiler needing to convert the MSIL in the DLLs to binary on first load please. On first load you mean - after a build? And, from the URL being entered in the browser, how does the .NET compiler know that it needs to convert the MSIL to binary?

Comment: Its how the framework was designed. All .NET based languages like C#, VB.NET, F#, IronPython all compile to an intermediate language called MSIL, which looks a bit like assembler. When execution occurs - whether its a website, a DLL or an EXE, the CLR will look at the machine it is running on (memory, CPU amongst) and then run the MSIL in binary that targets the specific CPU. The CLR is also known as 'interpreter', but its much more advanced than that.

Comment: Also see this StackOverflow question for some initial answers on how the CLR works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377187/how-net-framework-works

Comment: From the Url coming in, IIS is configured to push requests received via a specific URL to the .NET framework's Web components. They take the request apart, assemble information pertaining to the request and then run the code to which the endpoint is configured for.

Comment: May you update the answer with commented information and ill mark this as the answer.